# Switching to Lexilla

Tags: c, scintilla, lexilla

I am trying to switch my code to a new way of handling lexers in Scintilla.

This is what worked in previous versions of Scintilla, old ways:

```c
scintilla_send_message(widget, SCI_SETLEXER, SCLEX_CPP, 0);
```

Since around version 4.4 I must do it new ways. From reading documentation I believe it is something like this:

```
ILexer5 *lexer = CreateLexer("cpp");
scintilla_send_message(widget, SCI_SETILEXER, 0, lexer);
```

But I am gettin `ILexer5 is undefined` and `CreateLexer is undefined`. I am tryng to find appropriate headers and static libs to add to my code and a compiler switch list. Please help.

My current `GCC` switches include this:

```
~/scintilla/bin/scintilla.a -DGTK -DSCI_LEXER -lstdc++ -I~/scintilla/include
```

Note I am using C not C++.

Comment: Scintilla 5 documentation says the lexilla library is now a separate one, have you built it and included it in scintilla.a? If not, you should build lexilla and include it to the build as well.

Comment: the problem is that there is no `Lexilla.h` in `include`. There is such file in `src` but it is C++ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Lexilla.h` is now in the `lexilla` repository.](https://github.com/ScintillaOrg/lexilla/blob/3f319754b27efe3eb82b53d74e85860226287317/include/Lexilla.h)
[As of February it has `#ifdef __cplusplus` guards](https://github.com/ScintillaOrg/lexilla/commit/3f319754b27efe3eb82b53d74e85860226287317#diff-cf18206cec0742ad390d1a325da661f4101c66a08da659327f6745977eec401e), so it appears to support C as well.

If you still encounter issues, I'd suggest pasting the exact error message.